# Saving gyroscope data while capturing image

Tags: android, camera, sensors

I'm quite new to Android and currently doing a little camera app that could save gyroscope/accelerometer data samples of the moment from camera shutter open till its close. Basically, I initialize gyro sensor in image capture button listener (with `camera.takePicture()`) and stop the sensor within `ShutterCallback`. Here is my question. Should I write the recorded sensor data to a .txt everytime I get a new sample or is there some clever method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an app where I logged sensor data at the fastest rate (`SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST`).  I was worried about the performance issues related to constantly writing to a text file while doing other tasks, so I created an `AsyncTask` class to do it in the background.  The following code worked fine for me, even if the app was left running for hours.  In your case, since you only want to log for a short period of time, another idea would be to keep the log information in memory in a collection object (e.g. an `ArrayList<>`), and then log everything on the `ShutterCallback`.

```
public void LogSensor(long SystemTime, int SensorType, float[] SensorValues) {
    String LogString = Integer.toString(SensorType);
    for(int i=0; i<SensorValues.length; i++) LogString += "," + SensorValues[i];
    (new LogSensor_in_background()).execute(SystemTime+","+LogString);
}

private class LogSensor_in_background extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... LogStrings) {    
    // do logging
    return null; }
}
```